# How do you serialize the attributes in Java?

Tags: java, serialization, attributes

I'm writing a java application and I have several java beans (student, course, room, etc.); each bean has from 15 to 30 fields.
The GUI should give the possibility to view, insert, or edit every bean.  Also, I have tables that show the list of users or courses etc.

Is there a nice way to serialize the attributes in a way that I don't have to create a label and a textfield to insert every attribute for every bean, but the form is automatically generated?

At the moment I used this solution:

```
public class User {
    public enum UserAttributes{
        FirstName (0),
        LastName (1),
        Address (2);

        int index;

        private UserAttributes( int index ) {
            this.index = index;
        }

        public int getIndex() {
            return index;
        }
    }

    private int numberOfAttributes = UserAttributes.values().length;
    private String [] attributes = new String[ numberOfAttributes ];

    public void set( UserAttribute a, String value ) {
        attribute[ a.getIndex() ] = val;
    }

    public String get( UserAttribute a ) {
        return attribute[ a.getIndex ];
    }

}
```

This works, but it destroys the object oriented paradigm, and from a class diagram you cannot see the class structure.
Do you think it is an elegant solution or there could be a better one?

thanks

Comment: You need a framework of some kind, and there are many from which to choose.  Are you building a web application or a Swing/thick client app?

Comment: Standalone application with SWT

Comment: You could use reflection, e.g. `Class c = MyClass.getClass(); Field[] fields = c.getFields();`

Comment: yes, I also thought about that, but there could be fields that should be hidden, and what I posted is a short version of mine, that in the field of the enum contains more information, the real one is:
DateOfBirth ( 5, "Date of Birth", "\\d\\d/\\d\\d/\\d\\d\\d\\d", "The date of birth should be in the format 02/02/2012"),
that is: index, attribute name for labels, regular expression to check the value inserted and error message in case the regex does not match.

Comment: NakedObjects? Actually it (allegedly) gives poor UIs. Turns out you want to put a bit more effort in than slapping all the fields down uniformly. And if you're doing that, your "framework" may be getting in the way more than it helps.

Comment: But in this way I can automatically create queries to the db, tables for every bean, insertion/deletion forms in a way that nothing is hard-coded and all the components are reusable and flexible. It doesn't take a lot of time to implement my solution, and it is very flexible whenever I want to add or delete or change a field (this happen often with my customer!). The only problematic thing is that I don't like, it is not an elegant OO solution, i think.

Answer (score 0):

It is not serialization that you want.  Here is some code:

```
import java.text.Format;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public final class LearninFormatten
{
    enum ValueType
    {
        FirstName("First Name: ", null),
        LastName("Last Name: ", null),
        DateOfBirth("Date Of Birth: ", new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy"));

        private Format formatter; // Format definition of this field.
        private String label; // Label for this value in the gui.

        private ValueType(final String label, final Format formatter)
        {
            this.formatter = formatter;
            this.label = label;
        }

        /**
         * @return The formatter or null.
         * null indicates no formatting of the value.
         */
        public Format getFormatter()
        {
            return formatter;
        }

        public String getLabel()
        {
            return label;
        }
    }

    final class Value
    {
        private ValueType valueType;
        private Object value;

        public Value(final ValueType valueType, final Object value)
        {
            this.valueType = valueType;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public ValueType getValueType()
        {
            return valueType;
        }

        public Object getValue()
        {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        LearninFormatten learninFormatten = new LearninFormatten();
        Value[] someValues = new Value[3];

        calendar.clear();
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2011);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 7);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 27);

        someValues[0] = learninFormatten.new Value(ValueType.FirstName, "Cornelius");
        someValues[1] = learninFormatten.new Value(ValueType.LastName, "Snarlington");
        someValues[2] = learninFormatten.new Value(ValueType.DateOfBirth, calendar.getTime());

        learninFormatten.printValues(someValues);
    }

    private void printValues(Value[] valueArray)
    {
        for (Value current : valueArray)
        {
            Format formatter;
            String label;
            Object value = current.getValue();
            ValueType valueType = current.getValueType();

            formatter = valueType.getFormatter();
            label = valueType.getLabel();

            System.out.print(label);
            if (formatter != null)
            {
                System.out.println(formatter.format(value));
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(value.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```